# Parallelism in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, message-passing

What are the options for achieving parallelism in Python?  I want to perform a bunch of CPU bound calculations over some very large rasters, and would like to parallelise them.  Coming from a C background, I am familiar with three approaches to parallelism:

1. Message passing processes, possibly distributed across a cluster, e.g. *MPI*.
2. Explicit shared memory parallelism, either using *pthreads* or *fork()*, *pipe()*, et. al
3. Implicit shared memory parallelism, using *OpenMP*.

Deciding on an approach to use is an exercise in trade-offs.

In Python, what approaches are available and what are their characteristics?  Is there a clusterable *MPI* clone?  What are the preferred ways of achieving shared memory parallelism?  I have heard reference to problems with the *GIL*, as well as references to *tasklets*.

In short, what do I need to know about the different parallelization strategies in Python before choosing between them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, you describe a CPU bound calculation.  This is not Python's forte.  Neither, historically, is multiprocessing.

Threading in the mainstream Python interpreter has been ruled by a dreaded global lock.  The new [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) API works around that and gives a worker pool abstraction with pipes and queues and such.

You can write your performance critical code in [C](http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/integratingpython.html) or [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), and use Python for the glue.

Answer (score 6):

The new (2.6) [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module is the way to go. It uses subprocesses, which gets around the *GIL* problem. It also abstracts away some of the local/remote issues, so the choice of running your code locally or spread out over a cluster can be made later. The documentation I've linked above is a fair bit to chew on, but should provide a good basis to get started.

Answer (score 5):

[Ray](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an elegant (and fast) library for doing this.

The most basic strategy for parallelizing Python functions is to declare a function with the `@ray.remote` decorator. Then it can be invoked asynchronously.

```py
import ray
import time

# Start the Ray processes (e.g., a scheduler and shared-memory object store).
ray.init(num_cpus=8)

@ray.remote
def f():
    time.sleep(1)

# This should take one second assuming you have at least 4 cores.
ray.get([f.remote() for _ in range(4)])
```

You can also parallelize stateful computation using [actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), again by using the `@ray.remote` decorator.

```py
# This assumes you already ran 'import ray' and 'ray.init()'.

import time

@ray.remote
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def inc(self):
        self.x += 1

    def get_counter(self):
        return self.x

# Create two actors which will operate in parallel.
counter1 = Counter.remote()
counter2 = Counter.remote()

@ray.remote
def update_counters(counter1, counter2):
    for _ in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.25)
        counter1.inc.remote()
        counter2.inc.remote()

# Start three tasks that update the counters in the background also in parallel.
update_counters.remote(counter1, counter2)
update_counters.remote(counter1, counter2)
update_counters.remote(counter1, counter2)

# Check the counter values.
for _ in range(5):
    counter1_val = ray.get(counter1.get_counter.remote())
    counter2_val = ray.get(counter2.get_counter.remote())
    print("Counter1: {}, Counter2: {}".format(counter1_val, counter2_val))
    time.sleep(1)
```

It has a number of advantages over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

- The same code runs on a single multi-core machine as well as a large cluster.
- Data is shared efficiently between processes on the same machine using [shared memory and efficient serialization](https://ray-project.github.io/2017/10/15/fast-python-serialization-with-ray-and-arrow.html).
- You can parallelize Python functions (using tasks) and [Python classes (using actors)](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html).
- Error messages are propagated nicely.

[Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) is a framework I've been helping develop.

Comment: Note: Ray is not supported on windows as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much data you need to process and how many CPUs/machines you intend to use, it is in some cases better to write a part of it in C (or Java/C# if you want to use jython/IronPython)

The speedup you can get from that might do more for your performance than running things in parallel on 8 CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

There are many packages to do that, the most appropriate as other said is multiprocessing, expecially with the class "Pool".

A similar result can be obtained by [parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com/), that in addition is designed to work with clusters.

Anyway, I would say go with multiprocessing.