# How to make Naive Bayes classifier for large datasets in python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have large datasets of 2-3 GB. I am using (nltk) Naive bayes classifier using the data as train data. When I run the code for small datasets, it runs fine but when run for large datasets it runs for a very long time(more than 8 hours) and then crashes without much of an error. I believe it is because of memory issue.

Also, after classifying the data I want the classifier dumped into a file so that it can be used later for testing data. This process also takes too much time and then crashes as it loads everything into memory first.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Another question is that is there a way to parallelize this whole operation i.e. parallelize the classification of this large dataset using some framework like Hadoop/MapReduce?

Comment: Without more context and specific info on your situation it's difficult to help/answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must increase the memory dynamically to overcome this problem. I hope this link will helps you
[Python Memory Management](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html)

[Parallelism in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987980/parallelism-in-pythonin-python)