# Google sheets: splitting a task into many sub tasks to parallel update

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

In Google Sheets, I have a python task that goes through and copy a formula from one template and pastes it into all other sheets by specifying a key. The list of keys is about 1000 keys long and it updates pretty slowly.

Right now, I can manually chop up the list and run the code 10 times at once so I have 10 parallel instances updating all at once. But is there a way to avoid doing it manually? Here is the code

```
def copy_formula(self,source_key,target_key,sheetname,ranges):
    sh = self.gsheets.gc.open_by_key(source_key)
    wks= sh.worksheet(sheetname)
    cell_list = wks.range(ranges)

    sh1 = self.gsheets.gc.open_by_key(target_key)
    wks1= sh1.worksheet(sheetname)
    cell_list1 = wks1.range(ranges)

    for i in range(0,len(cell_list1)):  
        cell_list1[i].value=cell_list[i].input_value

    wks1.update_cells(cell_list1)
```

gsheets is from `gspread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to check out multiprocessing, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987980/parallelism-in-python), but I would caution that simultaneous calls to *Google* could be tricky. Even using the newer Google Sheets API v4 (which gspread may not avail itself of yet), there is [at least one documented concurrency issue when appending data](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/G0sUsBHlaZg).

Having said that, Google clearly does support concurrent editing in the web UI (including by multiple users), so I'd be surprised if you *couldn't* figure something out (possibly with the help of [gsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), a newer Python wrapper around the newer Google API).